# How can I center my menu in CSS?

Tags: css, menu, center

It's inside a div. If I float it right it goes to right , but if I type center it doesn't do nothing

Menu code in CSS looks like this:

```
.subheader .menu {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Google centered, widthless float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the menu display: inline-block; and add text-align: center; to the parent container.

Comment: did you remove the float? can you post a quick jsfiddle, I'll help you solve it.

Comment: No problem :) Just make sure to mark the question as resolved just incase anybody else runs into the same issue, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you need better design for your menu try the free CSS Menu builder on [Swimbi.com](http://swimbi.com)
No hustle with coding and centering.